# What is the reason behind many Muslim brothers turning their face right and left in Salah after the 2nd rakat?

Tags: salat, shia-sunni, qiblah

I have noticed that many Muslim brothers including Sunni as well as [Dawoodi Bohra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawoodi_Bohra) turn their faces towards right and then left after 2nd rakat of namaz, saying *Assalamualaykum wa rehmatullahi wa barakatahu*.

This is not the case with Shia ithna ashari brothers, they do not turn their faces away from Qiblah.

May I know the reason behind it, along with references as I need to understand whether I should turn my face or not?

Comment: How do you finish your salah?

Comment: @ozbek In my community, people used to turn their faces; I use to do the same. I need an answer so that I can rectify myself, if I am wrong..

Answer (score 2):

The Sunni tradition is based on the following ahadith:

https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/153:

> (22)Chapter: The salam to exit the prayer when one has finished and how it is done
>
> **'Amir b. Sa'd reported:**
>   I saw the Messenger of Allah (may peace be open him) pronouncing taslim on his right and on his left till I saw the whiteness of his cheek.

https://sunnah.com/nasai/12/114:

> (83)Chapter: The Takbir when sitting up from prostration
>
> **It was narrated from 'Abdur-Rahman bin Al-Aswad from his father-and Alqamah-that:**
>   Abdullah said: "I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say the Takbir every time he went down and got up, or stood or sat; he said the Salam on his right and his left: 'As-salamu alaykum wa rahmatulah (peace be upon you and the mercy of Allah ),' until the whiteness of his cheek could be seen." He said: "And I saw Abu Bakr and 'Umar, may Allah (SWT) be pleased with them both, doing the same."

https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/607:

> (340)Chapter: Regarding The Salam
>
> **Narrated Abdullah ibn Mas'ud:**
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) used to give the salutation to his left and right sides until the whiteness of his cheek was seen, (saying: "Peace be upon you, and mercy of Allah" twice.
>
> AbuDawud said: This is a version of the tradition reported by AbuSufyan. The version of Isra'il did not explain it. AbuDawud said: This tradition has been narrated by Zubayr from AbuIshaq and Yahya ibn Adam from Isra'il from AbuIshaq from AbdurRahman ibn al-Aswad from his father from Alqamah on the authority of Abdullah ibn Mas'ud. AbuDawud said: Shu'bah used to reject this tradition, the tradition narrated by AbuIshaq as coming from the Prophet (ﷺ).

And [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whiteness%20of%20his%20cheek%22%20site:sunnah.com) similar ones.

Comment: Would be better if you add shia references too.

Comment: @Ali_Waris: I don't have any knowledge on Shi'a view. That can be a separate answer.